# Jmockit @Mocked inside a helper class doesn't initialize

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

If I have the following;

```
public class ClassA {

   public void methodA(){
    System.out.println("In ClassA, methodA");
  }
}
public class ClassB {

  public void methodB(){
  }
}
```

and a junit test of;

```
@Test
public void testMocked(@Mocked final ClassB mockedB) {
    System.out.println("Mocked inline");
    new MockUp<ClassA>() {
        @Mock
        public void methodA() {
            System.out.println("Inline mockup, mockedB:" + mockedB);
        }
    };
    ClassA a = new ClassA();
    a.methodA();

}
```

Then when I run the test I get;

```
Mocked inline
Inline mockup, mockedB:jmockitpractice.ClassB@329b0985
```

Which is as expected, the classB is Mocked, and an instance is available.

But, if I change this to create a helper class for mocking,

```
public class MockHelper {
  @Mocked ClassB classB;
  public void setupMocks(){

    new MockUp<ClassA>() {

        @Mock
        public void methodA(){
            System.out.println("In setupMocks, classB:"+classB);
        }
    };
  }
}
```

and the junit becomes;

```
@Test
public void testMockedInClass() {
    System.out.println("Mocked in helper class");
    MockHelper mh = new MockHelper();
    mh.setupMocks();
    ClassA a = new ClassA();
    a.methodA();

}
```

the result I get is;

```
Mocked in helper class
In setupMocks, classB:null
```

classB is not initialized by the @Mocked inside MockHelper

I would like to have all the mocking in a helper class, rather than having to declare all the mocking in the test class.
Any ideas why this doesn't work?
Thanks.

Comment: what is the benefit of doing it that way?

Comment: I have many tests to write, and they will all need to setup the mocks the same way. Putting all the setups into single class will save a lot of duplicate code

Comment: Not duplicating the mocked classes. You should be able to use inheritance. Have each class that needs the common mocks extend your helper class

Comment: `@Mocked` (just like JUnit's `@Test` annotation) is only meant to be used inside a test class (on an instance field or on a test method parameter). But the real problem here is something else. The question should attempt to show *why* using `@Mocked` in a helper class would be useful. Just saying it "will save a lot of duplicate code" does not convince me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Dom Farr, the answer was inheritance.

```
public class MockHelper {

@Mocked
ClassB classB;

public void setupMocks() {

    new MockUp<ClassA>() {

        @Mock
        public void methodA() {
            System.out.println("In setupMocks, classB:" + classB);
        }
    };
}
}
```

and
    public class mockTest extends MockHelper {

```
@Test
public void testMockedInClass() {
    System.out.println("Mocked in helper class");
    setupMocks();
    ClassA a = new ClassA();
    a.methodA();

}

}
```

As the test class extends the helper, it now works;

```
Mocked in helper class
In setupMocks, classB:jmockitpractice.ClassB@5d54e317
```